# Scheduled tasks

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, batch-processing

Overview:- I need to download a csv file every 10 mins from an intranet site. This is done using a batch file.
To ensure that it happens with out any delay, i have set up multiple tasks using Windows tasks scheduler. 
The tasks runs successfully when i am active on the desktop.
Task fails when i logout. So to keep them active during weekend i keep my system locked.

Trouble:- When kept locked all the task begin to run simultaneously failing to update the file.

Question:- How can this be prevented.

Answer (score 0):

Could be lots of different things.  What credentials are the scheduled task(s) running under?  What commands are you running in your batch file?  How are you connecting to the other machine to download the file?

Just in general I would have your script write out a log file between each command so you can see at what point it is hanging at.  Does it not even really start to process, or does it try to make the connection and fail, or does it not copy the file, or does it not copy the file to the place you think it would copy it to, or do you just need to have exit at the end?